# Python and MySQL: is there an alternative to MySQLdb?

Tags: python, mysql, database

Is there a module written purely in Python that will allow a script to communicate with a MySQL database? I've already tried MySQLdb without success. It requires too much: GCC, zlib, and openssl. I do not have access to these tools; even if I did, I don't want to waste time getting them to work together. I'm looking for tools that will make my work easier.

Can someone point me in the direction of a MySQL Python module written in Python? If not, tips on writing my own code for communicating with MySQL would be appreciated.

Thanks,

Tony

---

Thanks everyone for your answers. Since I'm working with a small database (a few hundred records, mainly names and addresses) I've decided to use SQLite. I just discovered it. It seems to be perfectly suited for my purposes; it was simple to install (took about two minutes) and works well with Python. I'm stuck with Python 2.4 so I can't use the sqlite3 module, but I'm able to communicate with the database by using Python's 'subprocess.Popen' function and command-line parameters.

Comment: You should be able to find a prebuilt version of the library for your system.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Oracle implemented a pure python mysql connector, aptly named [mysql-connector-python](https://github.com/mysql/mysql-connector-python). It can be pip-installed and receives plenty of updates.

Note that it's GPL licensed, which may or may not be a problem for your prjoect. If you can't live with that, you can also pick up [PyMySQL](https://pypi.org/project/PyMySQL/) instead which is one of the few connectors that works well and is distributed under MIT.

Comment: It seems to be starting to live again.

Answer (score 5):

You've looked at these?

http://wiki.python.org/moin/MySQL

Answer (score 5):

Lately there is also [oursql](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/oursql/) ([docs](http://packages.python.org/oursql/)), which has various advantages over MySQLdb and other existing drivers -- listed at the top of the documentation.

Comment: The first "advantage" they list is fud.  "Real Parameterization?"  MySQLdb has that already.

Comment: @jcd: I believe that MySQLdb has no real parameterization. Check this: lists.mysql.com/internals/34723

Answer (score 3):

I had the problem that I wanted to write code which work for Python 2 and Python 3. I found [`pymysql`](https://pymysql.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) to fit perfectly. I did not have to adjust code to switch from MySQLdb to pymysql

### Installation

```
$ pip install PyMySQL
```

If you don't have admin rights:

```
$ pip install -u PyMySQL
```

### Usage

The usage is the same as for MySQLdb:

#### SELECT

```
import pymysql
import pymysql.cursors
connection = pymysql.connect(host=mysql['host'],
                             user=mysql['user'],
                             passwd=mysql['passwd'],
                             db=mysql['db'],
                             cursorclass=pymysql.cursors.DictCursor)
cursor = connection.cursor()
sql = ("SELECT `id`, `formula_in_latex` FROM `wm_formula` "
       "WHERE `is_important` = 1 "
       "AND id != 1 "  # exclude trash class
       "ORDER BY `id` ASC")
cursor.execute(sql)
formulas = cursor.fetchall()
```

### INSERT

```
import pymysql
connection = pymysql.connect(host=mysql['host'],
                             user=mysql['user'],
                             passwd=mysql['passwd'],
                             db=mysql['db'])
cursor = connection.cursor()
cursor.execute("INSERT INTO `toys` (`id`, `arrival`, `duration`) "
               "VALUES ('1', '2014-12-01', '123');")
connection.commit()
```

Comment: Same thing happened to me, I have Archlinux and the MySQL-python module needs some dev libraries that Archlinux doesn't have (neither I wanted to install them). This was a one line installation and run like a charm. BTW How do you do to escape strings in a insert query?

Comment: @astinx `pymysql.escape_string` or prepared statements (e.g. http://stackoverflow.com/a/6216651/562769)

Comment: pymysql.org link is dead

Answer (score 2):

You can find pre-built binary packages for MySQLdb and its dependencies for most operating systems.

http://sourceforge.net/project/showfiles.php?group_id=22307&package_id=15775

What platform are you running on?

Comment: The pre-built binary packages are out of date. They don't offer a Python 2.6 version or x64 packages for windows.

Comment: The platform is a HostGator account on a shared server. MySQL and Python 2.4 are built-in, but I don't have access to GCC, among other things.

Since the database is small, I'm thinking that perhaps SQLite is the way to go. I hear it's very easy to install and use.

Comment: Python 2.6 includes support for SQLite so that might be a good direction to go.

Comment: The OP has said he's stuck on python 2.4 so prebuilt binaries should be fine.

Answer (score 2):

As mentioned in earlier answer, MySQL Connector/Python implements the MySQL Server/Client completely in Python. No compiling, just installing.

Here are the links:
* https://launchpad.net/myconnpy
* code: https://code.launchpad.net/myconnpy
* download: https://launchpad.net/myconnpy/+download (development shapshots)

It's not complete yet, but it should have enough to keep you going.
(FYI, I am the maintainer)

Answer (score 1):

Without a doubt MySQLdb is the best solution, but if you can't use it…

If you have `libmysqlclient`.[`so`|`dll`], you could access it directly using [ctypes](http://docs.python.org/library/ctypes.html) module.

Comment: MySQLdb has a few dealbreaking limitiations, even 11 years later.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know there is no direct alternative.  The only thing I can think of is to use ODBC instead, via [pyodbc](http://pyodbc.sourceforge.net/).  The MySQL site has an ODBC connector you can [download](http://dev.mysql.com/downloads/connector/odbc/5.1.html).  But I've never used this approach myself, so I can't say how well it will work.