# Python Prepared Statements. Problems with SELECT IN

Tags: python, mysql, sql, prepared-statement

I'm having an issue with a prepared statement in Python I can't solve so far.

The Query, which should be execute is e.g.:

```
 SELECT md5 FROM software WHERE software_id IN (1, 2, 4)
```

So I tried to execute a Query like this:

```
software_id_string = "(2, 3, 4)"
cursor.execute("SELECT md5 FROM software WHERE software_id IN %s", 
                software_id_string)
```

The Problem is that there are '' added to the string --> '(2, 3, 4)', so that the Query will be:

```
SELECT md5 FROM software WHERE software_id IN ''(2, 3, 4)''
```

I've also tried to rebuild the Script like this:

```
software_id_string = " 1 OR software_id = 2"
cursor.execute("SELECT md5 FROm software WHERE software_id = %s", 
              software_id_string)
```

This works only for the first id, which will be submitted (in this case 1), because the OR-part won't be interpeted as an SQL Statement...

Is there any possibility to fix the issues with the prepared statements?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You need one placeholder for each item in your parameter list.
You can use string operations to get that part done:

1. Create one `%s` for each parameter, and
2. Join those together with a comma.

In the next step you can pass your two arguments to `execute()` as recommended in the [DB-API documentation](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0249/).

```
software_id_string = (1,2,4)
qry = '''SELECT md5 
           FROM software 
          WHERE software_id IN (%s)''' % ','.join(['%s']*len(software_id_string))
# // 'SELECT md5 FROM software WHERE software_id IN (%s,%s,%s)'
cursor.execute(qry, software_id_string)
```

Comment: This is a great Idea! Thank you very much!

Answer (score 2):

I recommend creating a type converter for explicit handling of `IN` clauses. This is the way the `psycopg2` module handles it:

```
from MySQLdb.converters import conversions

class SQL_IN(object):
    def __init__(self, seq):
        self.seq = seq

    @classmethod
    def escape(cls, obj, d):
        return '(' + ','.join((d[type(o)](o, d) for o in obj.seq)) + ')'

# add this before you call MySQLdb.connect()
conversions[SQL_IN] = SQL_IN.escape
```

Real example:

```
db = MySQLdb.connect()
cursor = db.cursor()

SQL = "SELECT * FROM emp WHERE emp_id IN %s"
in_values = (1, 2, 3)
cursor.execute(SQL, (SQL_IN(in_values),))
print cursor._last_executed
print cursor.fetchall()

SQL = "SELECT * FROM emp WHERE name IN %s"
in_values = ("bob", "fred")
cursor.execute(SQL, (SQL_IN(in_values),))
print cursor._last_executed
print cursor.fetchall()
```

Output:

```
SELECT * FROM emp WHERE emp_id IN (1,2,3)
((1L, 'bob'), (2L, 'larry'), (3L, 'fred'))
SELECT * FROM emp WHERE name IN ('bob','fred')
((1L, 'bob'), (3L, 'fred'))
```

Answer (score 0):

You want

```
cursor.execute("SELECT md5 FROM software WHERE software_id IN %s" % software_id_string)
```

i.e. a % instead of a comma

Comment: Thank you very much! Will this also prevent SQL-Injections? Or will it only replace %s with the software_id_string?

Comment: It will only replace %s with the software_id_string.

Comment: Not to be too pedantic, but this is unfortunately vulnerable to SQL injection. But even if you only had trusted input, the recommended way (pass separate arguments to `execute()`) is still preferable because you do not have to manually manage the quoting of values, the DB-API will handle it for you for free.

Comment: The software_id_string variable is set on the line before, not obtained from a user, so that's why I said it was OK.