# Unable to pass list to the SQL query in python

Tags: python, sql, sql-server, django

I am using the code bellow::

```
def GetDetails(request):

try:
    year=''
    month=[]
    results=[]
    conn = connections["connection1"]
    cursor = conn.cursor()
    year = request.GET.get('year')
    print(year)
    month = request.GET.getlist('month[]')
    response_list = []
    query = (" select Year,month,student_name,admission_date,class from admission_table\
    where MONTH(admission_date) in (' + ','.join(map(str, month)) + ') AND YEAR(admission_date) in ('"+year+"') AND class in ('"+class+"')")
    cursor.execute(query,month)

    rows = cursor.fetchall()
    print(rows)
    if rows:
        for row in rows:
            response_list.append({'year':row[0],'month':row[1],'student_name':row[2],'admission_date':str(row[3]),'class':row[4]})
except Exception as e:
    print(str(e))

return HttpResponse(json.dumps(response_list))
```

The error I am getting is:

```
('22018', "[22018] [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 13 for SQL Server][SQL Server]Conversion failed when converting the varchar value '.join(map(str,month)) + ' to data type int. (245) (SQLExecDirectW)")
```

The month variable has the value : ['01', '02', '03']

How can I achieve this ? Please help!
Thanks for time and help in advance!
I would appreciate the help.

Comment: MONTH(admission_date) in ('" + ','.join(map(str, month)) + "') do you miss the 2 " here?

Comment: Could you please give some examples as to how to use it ?

Comment: @charles I have added 2 " yet I am getting the same error. `select Year,month,student_name,admission_date,class from admission_table
    where MONTH(admission_date) in (' 01,02,03 ') AND YEAR(admission_date) in ('2019') AND class in ('9')`  where as the the **in operator needs(' 01','02','03 ')**

Comment: how about "','".join(map(str, month))?

Comment: String concatenation leads to SQL injection errors/attacks. Use Prepared Statements. You'll need to do a bit extra to get the right number of placeholders for the `IN` clause but the safety is worth it. https://stackoverflow.com/a/6216651/1324345

Comment: @charles Thank you so much. It is working fine now. Thanks again.