# SQL Conditional Count for Each Entry Instead of All

Tags: python, sql, select, count

I have the following query that is attempting to return authors and their article counts:

```
SELECT (
            SELECT COUNT(*)
            FROM aldryn_newsblog_article
            WHERE
                aldryn_newsblog_article.author_id IN (1,2) AND
                aldryn_newsblog_article.app_config_id = 1 AND
            aldryn_newsblog_article.is_published IS TRUE AND
            aldryn_newsblog_article.publishing_date <= now()
            ) as article_count, aldryn_people_person.*
            FROM aldryn_people_person
```

However, it is currently returning the same number for each author because it counts all articles for authors with ID's of 1 and 2.

How should the query be modified, so it returns proper article counts for each author?

On a separate note, how can one turn the `(1,2)` into a list that can be spliced into the query dynamically? That is, suppose I have a Python list of author IDs, for which I would like to look up article counts. How could I pass that information to the SQL?

Comment: You need to tie the subquery to the outer select statement. On the subquery `Where` clause, add `aldryn_newsblog_article.author_id = aldryn_people_person.author_id` or whatever the tying ID would be.

Comment: That's called a "correlated subquery".

Comment: Sample data and desired results would help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As commented, for a subquery to work you need to correlate it to the outer query usually by a unique identifier (assumed to be `author_id`) which appears to also be used for a filtered condition to be run in `WHERE` of outer query. Also, use table aliases for clarity between subquery and outer query.

```sql
SELECT main.*
       , (SELECT COUNT(*)
          FROM aldryn_newsblog_article AS sub
          WHERE
             sub.author_id = main.author_id   AND
             sub.app_config_id = 1            AND
             sub.is_published IS TRUE         AND
             sub.publishing_date <= now()
         ) AS article_count

FROM aldryn_people_person AS main
WHERE main.author_id IN (1, 2)
```

Alternatively, for a more efficient query, have main query `JOIN` to an aggregate subquery to calculate counts **once** and avoid re-running subquery for every outer query's number of rows.

```sql
SELECT main.*, 
       , sub.article_count

FROM aldryn_people_person AS main
INNER JOIN 
    (SELECT author_id
           , COUNT(*) AS article_count
     FROM aldryn_newsblog_article AS sub
     WHERE
        sub.app_config_id = 1            AND
        sub.is_published IS TRUE         AND
        sub.publishing_date <= now()
     GROUP BY author_id
    ) AS sub
  ON sub.author_id = main.author_id
  AND main.author_id IN (1, 2)
```

---

Re your separate note, there are many SO questions like [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6216503/python-prepared-statements-problems-with-select-in/6216651#6216651) that asks for a dynamic list in `IN` operator which involves creating a prepared statement with dynamic number of parameter placeholders, either `?` or `%s` depending on Python DB-API (e.g., psycopg2, pymysql, pyodbc). Then, pass parameters in second argument of `cursor.execute()` clause. Do note the limit of such values for your database.

```py
# BUILD PARAM PLACEHOLDERS
qmarks = ", ".join(['?' for _ in range(len([list_of_author_ids]))])

# INTERPOLATE WITH F-STRING (PYTHON 3.6+)
sql = f'''SELECT ...
          FROM ....
          INNER JOIN ....
            AND main.author_id IN ({qmarks})'''

# BIND PARAMS
cursor.execute(sql, [list_of_author_ids])
```

Comment: I am trying out the inner join version, but it seems to be getting the following error:

`django.db.utils.ProgrammingError: invalid reference to FROM-clause entry for table "main"
LINE 11:                     sub.author_id = main.author_id   AND
                                             ^
HINT:  There is an entry for table "main", but it cannot be referenced from this part of 
the query.`

Comment: It appears that a `LATERAL` may be needed instead of `JOIN`?

Comment: Whoops! Remove that `JOIN` pair since it should be handled outside the subquery (retained from first code block). See edit.

Answer (score 1):

The way I normally handle these sorts of aggregates is first design a query that gets a list of author names and articles, then create a column to serve as the article count. At the lowest level this looks silly, because every article is 1. Then I wrap that in a subquery and sum from it.

```
SELECT sub.author, articleCount = sum(sub.rowCount)
FROM (
   select distinct
     author = x.author_id
     , article = x.articleTitle
     , rowCount = 1
   from aldryn_newsblog_article x
   where x.author_id in (1,2) and x.is_pubished = true --whatever other conditions you need here
) sub
GROUP BY sub.author
```

As far as the (1,2) being replaced with something more dynamic, the way I've seen it done before is to use CHARINDEX to parse a comma separated string in the where clause so you would have something like

```
DECLARE @passedFilter VARCHAR(50) = ',1,2,'
SELECT * FROM aldryn_newsblog_article WHERE CHARINDEX(',' + CAST(author_id AS VARCHAR) + ',', @passedFilter, 0) > 0
```

What this does is takes your list of ids (note the leading and trailing commas) and lets the query do a pattern match on it off of the key value. I've read that this doesn't give the absolute best performance, but sometimes that isn't the biggest concern. We used this a lot in passing filters from a web app to SQL Server reports. Another method would be to declare a table variable / temp table, populate it somehow with the authors you want to filter for then join that subquery from the first bit of my answer to that table.