# Unable to install mysqldb on python

Tags: python

I am trying to install mysqldb for python on my windows PC but come across this error: (Note I know I am using an outdated version of python but this is the version I need to use for now)

[image]

Comment: Could you copy the last couple lines (red, yellow) into the question text itself so that this would be easier to find by google?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know if you need that specific module/package. But you can get the [official mysql-connector](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-python/en/) for python by specifying this package:

```
mysql-connector-python-rf
```

Works with both Python 2, and 3. ([link](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-python/en/connector-python-versions.html))

Answer (score 0):

The problem is more so that MySQL-Python does not support [*any* version of Python 3](https://python3wos.appspot.com/). You should look for an alternative connector library. The error message does not mean anything, only that in the past MySQL-Python at least tried to support 3.0 - 3.2 (before 3.3 was ever released), however they gave up.

Unfortunately, I personally am not using MySQL so I cannot comment about the alternatives; however [this question could be of use](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/677811/python-and-mysql-is-there-an-alternative-to-mysqldb).